# For $0 \leq a_n, b_n$: Is $\varliminf a_n \varlimsup b_n \leq \varlimsup a_n b_n $ true?

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

The sequences are assumed to be bounded!

I suspect it is, since $\varliminf a_n + \varlimsup b_n \leq \varlimsup (a_n+b_n)$ is. But I have not managed to prove it.

I thought it possible to mirror the following trick when proving the inequality for sums:

> $\varlimsup b_n = \varlimsup (a_n + b_n - a_n) \leq \varlimsup (a_n + b_n ) + \varlimsup(-a_n) = \varlimsup (a_n + b_n )  -\varliminf(a_n)$

But the incipient idea fell short rather fast:

> $0 = \varlimsup (a_n b_n - a_n b_n) \leq  \varlimsup (a_n b_n) + \varlimsup (-a_n b_n)$

I was hoping to manipulate $\varlimsup (-a_n b_n)$ in some ingenious way, but have not succeded.

Would love to read any ideas or hints.

Comment: Hm, can you just set $a,b=e^A,e^B$ and use the result for sums

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that the sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are bounded:

Let $\alpha = \liminf a_n$ and $\beta = \limsup b_n$ (the boundedness assumption telling us that $-\infty < \alpha,\beta < \infty)$.  Let $\epsilon > 0$.  By definitions, we know that $a_n > \alpha - \epsilon$ for all $n$ sufficiently large and that $b_n > \beta - \epsilon$ for infinitely many $n$.  Therefore also $a_n b_n > (\alpha - \epsilon)(\beta - \epsilon) = \alpha\beta - \epsilon(\alpha+\beta) + \epsilon^2$ for infinitely many $n$.  This implies that $\limsup (a_n b_n) > \alpha\beta - \epsilon(\alpha+\beta) + \epsilon^2$.  This holds for arbitrary $\epsilon$, so we conclude $\limsup(a_n b_n) \geq \alpha \beta$ as desired.

If either of the sequences is not bounded, there may be some other cases to check, but I am a bit too lazy to check them all :)

Comment: Forgot to include that detail, yes they are assumed bounded, sorry.
Thanks, the epsilon-proof is neat, so the statement is true as I suspected. I do however wonder if there is an alternative and slicker way to do it, as with the sums.

Comment: @kapython if you want you can remove boundedness assumption, as long as you assume there are no products like $0\cdot\infty$ or $\infty\cdot 0$. Recall that one of the definitions of $\limsup$ is $\limsup_{n\to \infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}a_k$. With this definition, note that for any $n$, we have $(\inf_{k\geq n}a_k)b_k \leq a_kb_k$, and hence $(\inf_{k\geq n}a_k)b_k\leq\sup_{k\geq n}(a_kb_k)$, and hence $(\inf_{k\geq n}a_k)\sup_{k\geq n}b_k \leq\sup_{k\geq n}a_kb_k$. Since $n$ was arbitrary, we can now take $n\to\infty$ to get $\liminf a_n \cdot \limsup b_n \leq \limsup(a_nb_n)$

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you for that later one, instructive!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the exponential function is continuous and increasing implies that liminfs and limsups pass through the exponential function. Setting $a_n=e^{A_n} ,\ b_n= e^{B_n}$ this turns the inequality into $$\exp(\liminf A_n + \limsup B_n) \le \exp(\limsup (A_n + B_n))$$ Since the exponential function is increasing we can cancel it on both sides which reduces it to the additive known result. Since this result is true for bounded sequences (including negative values), we are done.

Comment: Wow, that's an interesting and novel approach. However I'm failing in to outline the full details of this approach in order to yield the desired inequality; would you mind showing them?

Comment: Hi @kapython IMO the two things that I didn't explicitly write are $\liminf \exp(a_n ) = \exp(\liminf a_n)$ (similarly with limsup) and $\exp(A)\le \exp(B)$ iff $A\le B$. Can you prove these, and do they answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for those two, I'll have a go at them!

Comment: @kapython no problem, if you have any issues just ask. good luck!